# Js Validator Plugin Remote Rules for Unique Value Checking Without Refresh Page Not Working After Ajax Call

Tags: php, jquery, validation

I'm trying to validate an designation name with a remote rules. 
On first time form submit by entering `test` value, form submitted and value bind by ajax. but after second time without refresh page i m trying to submit form by adding same value `test` which i added. i m not getting error for existing name.

here is the js code

```
  $("#designationaddedit").validate({
     rules: {
         designation_name: {
             required: true,
         },
         designation_copy_name: {
             remote: {
                 url: base_url + 'Designation/designation_name_exists',
                 type: "post",
                 data: {
                    designation_copy_name: function() {
                        console.log("1");
                      return $( "#designation_copy_name" ).val();
                    }
                }
             }
         },
     },
     messages: {
         designation_name: {
             required: "Enter Designation name"
         },
         designation_copy_name: {
             remote: 'Designation name is already exists.'
         },
     },
 });


 $(document).on('submit', '#designationaddedit', function(event) {
         event.preventDefault();


         var designation_id = $('#designation_id').val();
         var designation_name = $('#designation_name').val();
         var action = $('#action').val();
         var table = $('#designationTable').DataTable();
         var info = table.page.info();
         var currentpage = info.start;

         if ($("#designationaddedit").valid()) {
             $('.preloader').show();
             $.ajax({
                 url: base_url + 'designation/add',
                 type: 'POST',
                 dataType: 'json',
                 data: { submit: 1, designation_id: designation_id, designation_name: designation_name, action: action },
                 success: function(response) {
                     $('.preloader').hide();
                      if (response.success == 1) {
                     $("#designation_model").modal('hide');

                     } else {

                     }
                 }
             });
         }
     })
```

Answer (score 0):

below code fixed my issue. I hope it's help you.

```
remote: { url: "http:url.com", type: "post", data: { USER_ID: userid }, async: false, // set async = false }
```